# I couldn't do what I want on react testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

When I click to increase button the value of the count is increasing so text in the h1 is also changing, but when I want to test it, its [failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMa96.png). When I change the expected value to 0 on the expect part, the test doesn't fail. What is the reason behind it? Appreciate your help.

Component that I want to test

```
import { useState } from "react"

function Counter() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{count}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increase</button>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>Decrease</button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Counter
```

My test code but I can't get my expected output from it.

```
import {screen, render} from "@testing-library/react"
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event"

import Counter from "."

test("counter component test", () => {
    render(<Counter />)

    const count = screen.getByText("0")

    const increaseBtn = screen.getByText("Increase")

    userEvent.click(increaseBtn);
    expect(count).toHaveTextContent("1")
})
```

Comment: I think you should either use the `waitForExpect` and/or use `act` from `@testing-library/react`

Comment: Thanks for the help, when I added waitFor in my test code before the expect part I got the expected output from it.

Comment: Yea, `waitFor` was the one i was referring to. Nice, i will post this as an answer for other people needing help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Testing components where you initiate some state change needs some "wait" time for it to change.

In your case you should use `waitFor` form the `@testing-library/react` and then assert in the callback:

```js
import {screen, render, waitFor} from "@testing-library/react"
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event"

import Counter from "."

test("counter component test", () => {
    render(<Counter />)

    const count = screen.getByText("0")

    const increaseBtn = screen.getByText("Increase")

    userEvent.click(increaseBtn);

    waitFor(() => {
      expect(count).toHaveTextContent("1");
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 14 the `user-event` APIs return promises.
You need to `await` those.

```
test('increase the count', async () => {
  // ...
  await userEvent.click(element)
  // ...
```

I recommend [`@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-floating-promises/)

---

Using an instance from `userEvent.setup()` instead of the direct APIs is recommended.

```js
test('increase the count', async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup()
  // ...
  await user.click(element)
  // ...
```

---

See https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro#writing-tests-with-userevent

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that you already solved your issue, just want to explain why you needed the `waitFor()`.

When you start your test you fetch for the `h1` element, and get it. And verify that the text inside it is "0".
At the end you test it again for the text to be "1". It fails because the text isn't "1". Why is it not "1"?

When you `setCount()` you told React to update the state, but React takes a few milliseconds to do exactly that.
So when you tried to check if the text was updated right after clicking, the text in fact was not updated, because state still wasn't updated.

Using `waitFor(() => {expect(count).toHaveTextContent("1")})` solves your problem because you wait the extra milliseconds React took to update your state, and therefore updating the `h1` element.

Comment: Also this is a very helpful explanation. Thanks for it.